# Testing if object implements interface (type alias)

Tags: typescript, testing, types, node.js-tape

I am using a minimal testing library ([Tape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape)) which has a handful of testing methods available similar to many test frameworks. I have a type alias and an object which implements it.

```
export type myType = {
   myFunc(cb: (val: string) => void): void
}

const myObj = {
   myFunc: (cb) => { return }
} as myType
```

Using how can I test that an object implements the `myType` type alias using `tape.equal(actual, expected)` or otherwise?

Comment: Your `myObj` code isn't valid JS syntax.  Please consider modifying the code to constitute a [mcve] suitable from dropping into an IDE to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Good catch, updated

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. You might want to test out your example code in an IDE like the TypeScript playground ([link](https://tsplay.dev/NalkBw)) to make sure it has no obvious typos or other problems.

Comment: Updated again. Thank you I will note that site for future SO use